# howto install l10n autofetch

Tags: drupal, extension, i18n, language

The l10n autofetch extension sounds great but I can't find any hint how to install it. Everybody seems to assume that this is self evident. Where should I put the downloaded folder? It contains only 4 files and I red the readme but it is still a mystery to me.

https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.l10n.update/

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The l10n update extension has not been compatible with CiviCRM since version 4.7 of CiviCRM was released in 2016 there does not appear to be any concerted effort underway to bring this extension up-to-date for CiviCRM 4.7+

Source: https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.l10n.update/issues/3

You can still install language packs into CiviCRM as before: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/i18n+Administrator%27s+Guide%3A+Using+CiviCRM+in+your+own+language however the l10n files will need to be updated manually when CiviCRM itself is updated.

Comment: Thank you for the input. But how we are supposed to add an other language in CiviCRM nowadays (5.1)? Ist there only the Transiflex method where everyone needs an account? (I am surprised that this discontinuation isn't mentioned in the [CiviCRM wiki](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/i18n+Administrator%27s+Guide%3A+Using+CiviCRM+in+your+own+language#i18nAdministrator%27sGuide:UsingCiviCRMinyourownlanguage-Updatingyourtranslationfilesusingthe%22l10nupdate%22extension(Recommended)) .)

Comment: You can still download and install language packs into CiviCRM the same as before https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile#i18nAdministrator'sGuide:UsingCiviCRMinyourownlanguage-UsingCiviCRMinanotherlanguagethanUS-English